# Are the numerical parameters of TranslateAnimation in dp or px?

Tags: android, translate-animation

I was reading through [the documentation of TranslateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation) and I saw that this is one of the many constructors of the TranslateAnimation class:

```
public TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, 
            float toXDelta, 
            float fromYDelta, 
            float toYDelta)
```

Reading further on what each of the parameters denote, I saw that `fromXDelta` means:

> Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the animation

[*...and so on for the other parameters.*]

**Question:**

I understand what these parameters imply but I do not know how to represent them. What's the metric and reference point? Are they meant to be in dp or pixels?

Comment: Pixels. Basically, most everything on the code side – excepting the unit conversion methods and such – is in pixels.

Comment: pick a sell bro(\*~\*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Like @Mike M. said, most dimensions on the code side are in 
>   **Pixel**.

However, this is not a hindrance as you can still convert easily from dp to px and back. Here are two functions you can use to achieve this:

dp to px:

```
public float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context) {
    return dp * ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

px to dp

```
public float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context) {
    return px / ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

**PS:**

If you need your returned dp value in `int` rather than `float`, you can just pass the value inside `Math.round()`.

I hope this helps someone out there. Merry coding!